# Android App Freezing on Returning from Call

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

As my android app open dialing app frequently using the following code

```
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(number))
{
    var context = Android.App.Application.Context;
    if (context == null)
         return;

    var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionDial, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("tel:" + number));
    intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
    context.StartActivity(intent);
}
```

The issue is that app freezes on returning it from a call on second time.
On first call, app works fine even after returning it from call but on dialing again when the user returns in our app to start using the application app freezes.
I've done nothing on OnResume and OnPause just called the base functions.

Users claiming that they are facing this issue after latest update on android 10 or 11.

I've fix some memory leak issues, but users doesn't observe any sort of improvement

Any help would be appreciable. btw I'm using Xamarin.forms and this code is used by implementing dependency service.

**Edited:**
This issue doesn't reproduce on all devices as but I have the log file where error was logged during crash

```
04-01 14:13:51.843 W InputDispatcher: channel '8f6beaa com.example.app/.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0xd, fd=469
04-01 14:13:51.843  3612  5985 E InputDispatcher: channel '8f6beaa com.example.app/crc64dc2be0a4ecbe1a27.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

Comment: According to the code you provided, we could not make sure what cause this issue. When you Freezing, any errors? Could you provide more details in your output window?

Comment: question edited

Comment: I have checked the logs. But it would not help us to confirm what caused this error. Could you make sure the specific device which thrown this error?

Comment: samsung galaxy note 9... this issue mostly occur in samsung galaxy series... not reproduced on all devices